# Python. Homework: Not working due to efficiency with large inputs

Tags: performance, python-3.x

Homework: return the maximal sum of k consecutive elements in a list. I have tried the following 3, which work for 6 of the 7 tests by which the solution is verified. The 7th test is a very long input with a very large k value. I cannot put the input list in because the shown list is truncated due to its length. Here are the 3 methods I tried. Reiterating, each timed out, while the last one also gave me a `SyntaxError`.
Method 1: [verbose]

```
def arrayMaxConsecutiveSum(inputArray, k):
    sum_array = []
    for i in range(len(inputArray)-(k+1)):
        sum_array.append(sum(inputArray[i:i+k]))

    return max(sum_array)
```

Method 2: [one line = efficiency??]

```
def arrayMaxConsecutiveSum(inputArray, k):

    return max([sum(inputArray[i:i+k]) for i in range(len(inputArray)-(k+1))])
```

Method 3: Lambda call

```
def arrayMaxConsecutiveSum(inputArray, k):
    f = lambda data, n: [data[i:i+n] for i in range(len(data) - n + 1)]

    sum_array = [sum(val) for val in f(inputArray,k)]

    return max(sum_array)
```

Some examples of inputs and (correct) outputs:

- IN:[2, 3, 5, 1, 6]
  k: 2 OUT: 8
- IN:[2, 4, 10, 1]
  k: 2 OUT: 14
- IN: [1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4]
  k: 4 OUT: 13

Again, I would like to mention that I passed the other tests (6 was very long with a large k value as well[k was an order of magnitude smaller than 7's, however]) and just need to identify a method or a revision that would be more efficient/make these more efficient. Lastly, I would like to add that I attempted both 6 and 7 with the (truncated) inputs on IDLE3 and each produced a `ValueError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ryanflynn/arrmaxconsecsum.py", line 15, in <module>
    962, 244, 390, 854, 406, 457, 160, 612, 693, 896, 800, 670, 776, 65, 81, 336, 305, 262, 877, 217, 50, 835, 307, 865, 774, 163, 556, 186, 734, 404, 610, 621, 538, 370, 153, 105, 816, 172, 149, 404, 634, 105, 74, 303, 304, 145, 592, 472, 778, 301, 480, 693, 954, 628, 355, 400, 327, 916, 458, 599, 157, 424, 957, 340, 51, 60, 688, 325, 456, 148, 189, 365, 358, 618, 462, 125, 863, 530, 942, 978, 898, 858, 671, 527, 877, 614, 826, 163, 380, 442, 68, 825, 978, 965, 562, 724, 553, 18, 554, 516, 694, 802, 650, 434, 520, 685, 581, 445, 441, 711, 757, 167, 594, 686, 993, 543, 694, 950, 812, 765, 483, 474, 961, 566, 224, 879, 403, 649, 27, 205, 841, 35, 35, 816, 723, 276, 984, 869, 502, 248, 695, 273, 689, 885, 157, 246, 684, 642, 172, 313, 683, 968, 29, 52, 915, 800, 608, 974, 266, 5, 252, 6, 15, 725, 788, 137, 200, 107, 173, 245, 753, 594, 47, 795, 477, 37, 904, 4, 781, 804, 352, 460, 244, 119, 410, 333, 187, 231, 48, 560, 771, 921, 595, 794, 925, 35, 312, 561, 173, 233, 669, 300, 73, 977, 977, 591, 322, 187, 199, 817, 386, 806, 625, 500, 1, 294, 40, 271, 306, 724, 713, 600, 126, 263, 591, 855, 976, 515, 850, 219, 118, 921, 522, 587, 498, 420, 724, 716],6886)
  File "/Users/ryanflynn/arrmaxconsecsum.py", line 6, in arrayMaxConsecutiveSum
    return max(sum_array)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

(Note: this used method 3) I checked with print statements both the value for `f(inputArray,k)` and `sum_array`: `[]` Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: How long exactly is the list and what is the value of `k` for this 6th test?

Comment: @wilusdaman k: 6886 for test 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
def arrayMaxConsecutiveSum(inputArray, k):
    S = sum(inputArray[:k])
    M = S
    for i in range(len(inputArray) - k):
        S += ( inputArray[i+k] - inputArray[i])
        if M < S:
            M = S
    return M
```

S stands for sum and M stands for max.

This solution have a complexity of O(n), when your's have O(n*k)

You are summing k numbers n-k times, when I am summing 3 numbers n times.

Comment: Interestingly, this works for test 7 but not test 4: inputArray: [3, 2, 1, 1]
k: 1. The correct answer is 3, but this yielded 2. Could you elaborate on what lines 5-7 do?

Comment: There should be M = S instead of M = 0. Answer has been edited.

Comment: Line 5 changes sum from index i to i+k into sum from index i+1 to i+k+1, lines 6 and 7 just checks if this id new max

Comment: This works, thank you. Before I accept this answer, I would just like to understand your thought process, and how exactly this works. So S is the sum of the first k elements, and to start M is the same. Then for each i, the sum group is moved over 1* (example index 0 to 2 then moved to 1 to 3) then if the sum of this group is more than the last, the last sum (most sum) is updated. then return the (most) right?

Comment: in regards to my *, how does line 5, more specifically the += and what is in parenthesis, "shift the sum group over 1"? I am not familiar with this syntax. Thanks

Comment: Parenthes are unnecessary. += is just shortcut. A += 7 is the same as A = A + 7.

Comment: You can notice that second sum is greater by k+1th element but less by 1st element than first sum, third sum is  greater by k+2th element but less by 2nd element than second sum...

Comment: Your second comment explained what I was looking for, thank you.